# complete intersection subvariety is given by regular sequence

Tags: algebraic-geometry

We say $X=V_+(f_1,\dots,f_r) \subseteq \mathbb{P}^n_k$ is a complete intersection if $X$ is of pure dimension $n-r$.

My question is, does that imply that $f_1,\dots,f_r$ is a regular sequence, i.e. $\times f_{i+1}: k[x_0,\dots,x_n]/(f_1,\dots,f_i) \longrightarrow k[x_0,\dots,x_n]/(f_1,\dots,f_i)$ is injective for all $i$.

---

**Here is my attack:**

Note first that we need only to show the multiply-by-$f_r$ map
$$
\varphi: k[x_0,\dots,x_n]/(f_1,\dots,f_{r-1}) \longrightarrow k[x_0,\dots,x_n]/(f_1,\dots,f_{r-1})
$$ is injective.
Let $\mathfrak{m}$ be a maximal ideal of $k[x_0,\dots,x_n]$ containing $f_1,\dots,f_{r-1}$. We want to show that $\varphi_\mathfrak{m}$ is injective for all such $\mathfrak{m}$.

If $\mathfrak{m}$ does not contain $f_r$ then $f_r$ is invertible in $k[x_0,\dots,x_n]_\mathfrak{m}/(f_1,\dots,f_{r-1})$ hence $\varphi_\mathfrak{m}$ is multiplication by an invertible element and hence injective.

If $\mathfrak{m}$ contains $f_r$, note that $k[x_0,\dots,x_n]_\mathfrak{m}$ is Cohen-Macaulay, hence
$$
\dim \Big( k[x_0,\dots,x_n]_\mathfrak{m}/(f_1,\dots,f_r) \Big) = n-r \Longleftrightarrow f_1,\dots,f_r \text{ is $k[x_0,\dots,x_n]_\mathfrak{m}$-regular}
$$
Thus $\varphi_\mathfrak{m}$ is injective.

---

I wonder if the statement (complete intersection implies regular sequence) holds and if my proof is correct. Any help would be appreciated.